# Proof of an inequality (by induction?)

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, induction

I came across the following inequality in the introduction of Apostol's Calculus, where he discusses the method of exhaustion. I tried to prove it for arbitrary $p$ by induction, but couldn't.

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^p < \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} < \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^p \qquad n,p\in\mathbb{N}
$$

Comment: The two sums are left and right Riemann sums for $\int_{0}^n x^p\,dx$.

Comment: Hint: integral test

Comment: @lulu: In Apostol's book, it is a pre-integral exercise.

Comment: @Bernard  For general $p$?  For natural numbers, the middle term is the lead term in the power sum...but for real $p$?

Comment: For a natural number, as far as I remember.

Comment: It's not an exercise, it's just provided for an exercise. I just had a go out of curiosity, but it seems induction is not the way to go here.

Comment: Try fixing $p$ and then use induction on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it
without the mean value theorem
by noting that,
if $0 \le a \lt b$,
$b^n-a^n
=(b-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^k b^{n-1-k}
$
so
$b^n-a^n
\lt (b-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b^k b^{n-1-k}
= n(b-a)b^{n-1}
$
and
$b^n-a^n
\gt (b-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^k a^{n-1-k}
= n(b-a)a^{n-1}
$.

If $b = a+1$,
this gives
$na^{n-1}
\lt (a+1)^{n}-a^n
\lt n(a+1)^{n-1}
$.

Summing for
$a=0$ to $m$,
$$\sum_{a=0}^m na^{n-1}
\lt \sum_{a=0}^m ((a+1)^{n}-a^n)
\lt \sum_{a=0}^m  n(a+1)^{n-1}
$$
or
$$n\sum_{a=0}^m a^{n-1}
\lt (m+1)^n
\lt n\sum_{a=0}^m  (a+1)^{n-1}
= n\sum_{a=1}^{m+1}  a^{n-1}
$$
so
$$\sum_{a=0}^m a^{n-1}
\lt \dfrac{(m+1)^n}{n}
\lt \sum_{a=0}^m  (a+1)^{n-1}
= \sum_{a=1}^{m+1}  a^{n-1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by the Mean Value Theorem, if that's "allowed":
$$n^{p+1}=\sum_{k=1}^n(k^{p+1}-(k-1)^{p+1})=\sum_{k=1}^n(p+1)c_k^p\ ,$$
where the $c_k$ are certain constants with
$$k-1<c_k<k\ .$$
Hence
$$n^{p+1}<\sum_{k=1}^n(p+1)k^p\ ,$$
and the other side of the inequality can be done similarly.